# Should the container port and application port be the same for deployments in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I know that I communicate with the outside world through the node port, but I have a question about setting up the container port in the internal delpoyments.

When creating an image, I am curious whether the application port and the container port of deployments must be set to be the same for communication to occur.

I connected the node port and the container port and tested it in the same environment by making the container port the same as or different from the application port.
In this method, the container port and application port must be the same to connect properly.
In the official document, the container port was the same as the application port without a clear explanation. It didn't seem like it would be a problem since I just had to change the service port and map it. (If it's a problem, please point it out.)

Below is my deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: staging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: echoserver
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: echoserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: k8s.gcr.io/e2e-test-images/echoserver:2.5
        name: echoserver
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 256Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 256Mi
```

and This is the aws nlb service yaml content.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echoserver-lb
  namespace: staging
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    run: echoserver
```

If you check by connecting to the container with kubectl exec, port 8080 is normal, but if you modify the container port(80), access to that port is not possible.

1. What I'm suspicious of is, other than the method I did, is there a way to connect with different container ports and application ports?
2. If the two ports must be the same, they look similar to the container port and application port in Docker. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service's `targetPort` must match the port the process in the Pod is actually listening on.  It does not need to match the Service's `port`.  The Pod's `containerPort` on its own doesn't necessarily mean anything.

For example, if the Service declares

```yaml
ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
```

then calling the standard HTTP port 80 on the Service will forward to port 3000 in the Pod; the Pod's `containerPort` isn't considered.

The place where `containerPort` is useful is in giving a name to a port.  You can say "this Pod serves HTTP on port 3000", and then "this Service forwards port 80 to the Pod's HTTP endpoint".  For example,

```yaml
---
# deployment.yaml
ports:
  - name: http
    containerPort: 3000
---
# service.yaml
ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

The Service's `port`/`targetPort` are in fact conceptually similar to the `docker run -p` option, except that the port remapping happens inside the cluster and isn't by default visible from outside the container system.

Comment: If you have any relevant documentation on this, I would really appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: The core [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) documentation is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly what you are asking.

You are asking about can have the different between port of pod, port of service and port of nodePort. And the answer is yes.

For example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 81
      nodePort: 30000
  type: NodePort
```

The port, targetPort and nodePort are diffrent.

[image]

This is the image for more detail about NodePort. The IPs of them are diffrent, so don't need the same port for them.

Comment: I understand what role a node port plays. The main question is whether the container port of deployments and the application port of images must match.

Comment: Don't need. When you create Dockerfile, you can expose 2 port of container and application are different: ```EXPOSE 5002 80```

Comment: I know that it works well that way in dockerfilie. However, if I set the container port and application port differently in the deployment in Kubernetes, it did not work properly. Did I configure it wrong?

Comment: Can you share your yaml file ?

Comment: I modified the question and added the corresponding yaml.

Comment: Hmm. Not problem with your yaml file. Have you exposed port 8080 and port 80 in your Dockerfile. And can you share the error message when you port 8080 instead of port 80 ?

Comment: Beside, can you share your yaml file that define nodePort service ?

Comment: When I checked the pod and service with kubectl describe, I saw a message saying it was successful.
However, when I tried to connect from the outside, connection refused occurred.

Comment: Since I am connecting through aws  nlb, I created a load balancer using service and connected it. And I will add the yaml content to the body.

Comment: Oh you are using LoadBalance, not NodePort. in your service file, if you not define the targetPort field, Kubernetes will default to using the same port as the port field for the targetPort. And in your case, it is port 8080. But your application is running is port 80 and it's not correct. So you can add ```targetPort: 80 # Assuming your application listens on port 80``` in your service file and try again.

Comment: However, shouldn't the connection be made by setting the container port to 8080 in deployments? I understand that the target port and container port are connected, and the container port and application port are connected.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And in my opinion, I usually use the same port for target port, container port and application port.

Comment: So, must the container port and application port be the same? Isn't it set up differently in docker? What's the reason?

Comment: It can. You can define like this:
```Application port: 80 (in your code of application)

- Container port: 8080 (in your dockerfile with expose)

- Target port: 8080 (must be the same with container port)

- Service port: 8081 (define in service file with attribute port)
```

Comment: If configured that way, the connection did not work. Did I configure it wrong?

Comment: when you tried to connect from the outside, which address has been typed ? http://{ip} or http://{ip}:8081 ?

Comment: I guess I'll have to test it again.